# Adding labels to plotly map created using plot_geo

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a choropleth map created using `plotly::plot_geo`. I would like to add labels on top of the map so that, for instance, over the location of Alabama on the map, it would say 'AL (68)', but for all states, as in the example below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

density <- sample(1:100, 50, replace = T)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

plot_geo() %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~density, text = state.name, span = I(0),
    locations = state.abb, locationmode = 'USA-states'
  ) %>%
  layout(geo = g)
```

Comment: There is an example given [here](https://plotly-r.com/maps.html#maps-custom), in Section 4.1.2 Choropleths - you can find it hosted [here](https://plotly-r.com/interactives/us-density-geojson.html).

Comment: I'm new to R. In python, you can annotate text using scattergeo(), which I created by modifying the official sample in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qc8qdI2aaFsf3fEsrcscWjjhl-2s8DJk?usp=sharing). I have modified the official sample in Colab to create it. If this code is ok, I will answer. The sample data only has state names, but I think your data has numeric data, so if you concatenate the state names with the numeric values, you can get the desired shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example, this is possible with `plotly::plot_ly()`

```
set.seed(1)

density <- sample(1:100, 50, replace = T)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
  )

plot_ly() %>%
  layout(geo = g) %>%
  add_trace(type = "choropleth", locationmode = 'USA-states',
            locations = state.abb,
            z = ~density, text = state.name,
            color = ~density, autocolorscale = TRUE) %>%
  add_trace(type = "scattergeo", locationmode = 'USA-states',
            locations = state.abb, text = paste0(state.abb, "\n", density),
            mode = "text",
            textfont = list(color = rgb(0,0,0), size = 12))
```

Output is:

[image]

Still not sure how to do this with `plotly::plot_geo()`, but this solution does allow you to stay within the plotly family.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is reasonably possible in R, at least for the time being. However, this is supported in python (see @r-beginners comment and https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/).

I am showing a couple of examples of alternative approaches using ggplot and leaflet, but each presents considerable drawbacks if you are wedded to plotly. Mapbox appears to be another option, but I have never used it. Examples using all of these packages in the article that was already linked in the comments (https://plotly-r.com/maps.html).

Example dataset

```
library(sf)

set.seed(1)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$density <- sample(1:100, nrow(nc), replace = T)

nc$lat <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc))[,"Y"]
nc$lon <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc))[,"X"]
```

Plot with ggplot (static)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = density)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = lon, y = lat),
    label = paste0(nc$NAME, "\n", "(", nc$density, ")"),
    check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_void()
```

Plot with leaflet (interactive)

```
library(leaflet)
library(viridis)

pal <- colorNumeric(viridis_pal(option = "C")(2), domain = nc$density)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  setView(-80, 34.5, zoom = 6.2) %>% 
  addPolygons(
    data = nc,
    fillColor = ~pal(nc$density),
    fillOpacity = 0.8,
    weight = 0.2,
    smoothFactor = 0.2,
    popup = ~density) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(
    lng = nc$lon,
    lat = nc$lat,
    label = paste0(nc$NAME, "\n", "(", nc$density, ")"),
    #label = "LABEL",
    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, textOnly = TRUE)) %>%
  addLegend(
    pal = pal,
    values = nc$density,
    position = "bottomright",
    title = "Density")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tmap` in view-mode allows to reach nearly what you want (shapes are used via the `urbnmapr` package):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(urbnmapr)

states <- get_urbn_map("states", sf = T) %>%  
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(density = sample(1:100, 51, replace = T)) %>% 
  mutate(abbvAndDens = str_c(state_abbv, " (", density, ")")) %>% 
  st_as_sf() 

tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(states) +
tm_fill("density",
        palette = "viridis",
        style = "cont",
        breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
tm_borders(lwd = .5, col = "black") +
tm_text("abbvAndDens", size= .75, col = "black")
```

[image]